# Geting error using seesaw on the lein repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Trying to go through [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/daveray/1441520) for seesaw gui library i get the following error as i run `lein repl`.
Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
WARNING!!! version ranges found for:
[seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/tools.trace]] -> [j18n "1.0.1"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "[1.2,1.5)"]
Consider using [seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure org.clojure/tools.trace]].
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.apropos: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.classpath: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: response-for in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/classpath.clj:15)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.complete: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.debug: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.format: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defprotocol+ in this context, compiling:(deps/cljfmt/v0v1v10/deps/rewrite_clj/v0v4v12/rewrite_clj/node/protocols.clj:9)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.info: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.inspect: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.macroexpand: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: response-for in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/macroexpand.clj:73)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.ns: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.pprint: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.refresh: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.resource: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defsource in this context, compiling:(deps/compliment/v0v2v4/compliment/sources/resources.clj:42)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.test: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: some-> in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/util/cljs.clj:57)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.trace: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: response-for in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/trace.clj:16)
Error loading cider.nrepl.middleware.undef: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: response-for in this context, compiling:(cider/nrepl/middleware/undef.clj:19)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: cider.nrepl.middleware.apropos/wrap-apropos in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init2232335588436189028.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6416)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3503)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6411)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3503)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6411)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.access$100(Compiler.java:37)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5837)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6177)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5572)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5008)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3629)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6407)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6216)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6462)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6455)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6863)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:282)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:287)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:315)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:348)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:405)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: cider.nrepl.middleware.apropos/wrap-apropos in this context
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$TheVarExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:613)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6409)
    ... 34 more**
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include (...) shortest code necessary to reproduce __it in the question itself__._

Comment: This looks like it could be a cider issue. Try removing cider and the Java agent and try again.

Comment: @DanielCompton: how could i remove cider and the java agent? and try again?

Comment: Remove the dependency on Cider, probably from your profile.clj, and don't use the Java agent when running the program.

Comment: @DanielCompton which line is the cider dep ? here is my project.clj: `(defproject sisaw "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [seesaw "1.4.2-SNAPSHOT"]])` and what does mean not using java agent? in the tutorial to which i refered above all the test are being made in the repl

Comment: It's probably in ~/.lein/profile.clj

Comment: i removed the dep cider, doesnt work

Comment: i still get the following error when i try to run `lein repl`: `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
WARNING!!! version ranges found for:
[seesaw "1.4.2"] -> [j18n "1.0.1"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "[1.2,1.5)"]
Consider using [seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]].
`

Comment: teymuri, are you on ubuntu 15? i found this, could be related to your issue: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/7082

Comment: oh No! yes i use ubuntu 15. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: try this: `unset JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` just before starting the repl.

Comment: @teymuri You're confused, there's no mention of Nixos in this question, and your error doesn't have any `-javaagent failed` message. changing `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is almost certainly useless

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this error:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: some->
```

`some->` has been [added in clojure 1.5](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-%3E)

Your `project.clj`, which you wrote in a comment (you should've added to question by editing it... leaving it into the comments is almost unreadable and hostile to people that might be willing to help you) is:

```
(defproject sisaw "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url  "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}  
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"         ]
                 [seesaw              "1.4.2-SNAPSHOT"]])
```

seesaw apparently is built upon clojure 1.4  [[1]](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw#features) [[2]](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/ef46cc8968dffbf534a4d5b01c33b9ecc1446948/project.clj#L23)

Leiningen is telling you:

> WARNING!!! version ranges found for: [seesaw "1.4.2"] -> [j18n "1.0.1"] -> [org.clojure/clojure "[1.2,1.5)"] Consider using [seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]

I understand `[1.2,1.5)` to mean a range from 1.2 to 1.5 with 1.2 included, 1.5 excluded

This means that a transitive dependency of seesaw prevents you from having clojure 1.5 as a dependency

Leiningen suggests to use `[seesaw "1.4.2" :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]]` in your dependencies, so that the version resolution will pick up the one specified somewhere else (in your project.clj in this case) and ignore/exclude the one derived from seesaw (transitive) dependencies

I don't know if this is the only problem that you have, but it should at least partly explain it